# Error in Swift when using UIImageView with selector @objc C function when reading sender.tag

Tags: swift, uiimageview, tags

An image sends an action to an @objc C function when pressed:

```
 let imageView = UIImageView()
 imageView.tag = 3
 imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ItemAction)))
 imageView.image = UIImage(named: (itemDictionary[character.Equipment[imageView.tag]]!.image))
 overlayView.addSubview(imageView)
```

this is the function that should be called:

```
@objc func ItemAction(sender: UIImageView!) {

    print(sender.tag)
    print("Item pressed from sender ")

}
```

the function runs, but when it comes to printing the sender tag I get an error message and the program quits:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002b42a00'

The whole setup with a UIButton works.
How can I read the tag of an UIImageView in an external function?

Comment: This well know error means that the sender is an object of class `UITapGestureRecognizer`, not of `UIImageView`. It's implicitly said on the doc of the parent class `UIGestureRecognizer` methods should be like: "@IBAction func myActionMethod()
@IBAction func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
  @objc func itemAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if let tag = sender.view?.tag{
            print("ImageView tag \(tag)")
        }
    }
```

in your function change your method signature to

```
@objc func ItemAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: @NathanaelTse glad it helped :)